# Problem on special functions

Tags: special-functions

What does the symbol PolyLog^{(0,1)}(0,1/e) mean? I know the meaning of the Polylogarithm, but what is that exponent? It happens the same with the Lerch zeta function!! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Assuming this is a question on *Mathematica* (see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), could you post the input form of your code.  I can't decipher it.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.

Comment: It's the (partial) derivative with respect to the second argument. That is, `Derivative[0, 1][PolyLog][0, 1/E]`.

Comment: Use `FullForm` if you're confused about the structure of an expression.